# Get all divs under a div with known ID and iterate over it

Tags: c#, foreach, html-agility-pack, dom

I'm building an app that crawls OkCupid matches.  Their match result contains Html that looks like this.

```
<div id="match_results">
    <div>person1</div>
    <div>person2</div>
    <div>person3</div>
</div>
```

I want to do a `foreach` person's div inside the div `match_results`.  However, something's not quite right with my C# code.  `matchesList` only contains one element (itself?  and not all the divs inside it...)

```
HtmlDocument matchesHtmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
matchesHtmlDoc.LoadHtml(matches);

string matchResultDivId = "match_results";

// match results
HtmlNodeCollection matchesList = matchesHtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id = '" + matchResultDivId + "']");

foreach (HtmlNode match in matchesList)
{
    //test
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those child divs are loaded on the page initially and not pulled in dynamically by javascript?

Comment: @Nate: The page is already loaded to completion via `WebClient.DownloadString("match?query...")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to select child divs:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(matches);

string matchResultDivId = "match_results";
string xpath = String.Format("//div[@id='{0}']/div", matchResultDivId);
var people = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath).Select(p => p.InnerText);

foreach(var person in people)
    Console.WriteLine(person);
```

Output:

```
person1
person2
person3
```